# Yesod auth: redirecting user to registration page

Tags: authentication, haskell, yesod

I'm playing with scaffolded site and i want to send user to the registration page after he logged in for the first time with OpenID or Google Account.

I've came up with this:

```
getAuthId creds = runDB $ do
        x ←  getBy $ UniqueUser $ credsIdent creds
        case x of
            Just (Entity uid _) → return $ Just uid
            Nothing → do
                return $ Just $ Key (PersistInt64 0)
```

And in `HomeR` handler i check for UserId value, showing registration form in case of zero.

This approach works, but seems hackish. What is the proper way to deal with such problem?

Comment: Why not return "Nothing" instead of a dummy key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend splitting the information up into two entities: a `User` entity that tracks the user's credentials, and a `Profile` entity containing the registration information. For example:

```
User
    ident Text
    UniqueUser ident
Profile
    user UserId
    displayName Text
    UniqueProfile user
```

In `getAuthId`, you'll either return an existing `UserId`, or if one doesn't exist, create a new entry. In `HomeR`, you'll get if there's a `Profile` (`getBy $ UniqueProfile uid`), and if not, display the registration form.

Comment: Hmm, but if user decides to not register, i'll end up with dangling record. On the contrary, not a big deal, right?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. All the `User` table is doing is giving some ID for idents. It's really just an efficiency measure: you could equivalently just use the actual identifier in place of UserId, but I think this is cleaner. If you're really worried about dangling records, you could run a cleanup job every so often to remove them.