# Make sure that user provided basic information for the profile

Tags: yesod

I have a login flow similar to the one described in this question [Yesod auth: redirecting user to registration page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760958/yesod-auth-redirecting-user-to-registration-page)

After the user logs in using one of the methods (Persona,Facebook,Google+) he gets redirected to the page where he is asked to fill in the basic information about his profile (Name, Email, etc), app tries to pick up as much information as possible from the login provider and prefill the profile fields for user. After user submits the profile form, he gets redirected back to the page where he came from (this is important, I don't want to redirect them back to HomeR as in the linked above question).

Now about the implementation. My models look basically like this:

```
User
    ident Text
    profile Profile Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable Show
Profile
    name  Text
    email Text
    deriving Typeable Show
```

For non existing users I create a `Nothing` profile in `getAuthId`. After that in `onLogin` I check if the user has a profile, and redirect it to `CreateProfileR` if it doesn't. In `CreateProfileR` I render the form, receive the input and then use `redirectUltDest` so that the user goes back to where it came from.

Everything works nicely, however there is one problem. If the user misbehaves and leaves the `CreateProfileR` without filling in his profile, I would end up with logged-in user, who didn't provide essential information. Which is no good.

So what I want is to redirect the user to `CreateProfileR` as long as it doesn't submit his profile.

As I don't want to handle it in all my Handlers, I tried to perform that in `maybeAuthId`. But if I do so, the user simply get stuck on the `CreateProfileR` (I guess I could avoid it by extracting the route from the request and making `CreateProfileR` an exceptional route which wouldn't redirect to itself, but that doesn't seem like a nice solution to me).

It seems that `maybeAuthId` is not the right place for that, but I can't find a good solution for the problem. What do you think is the right way?

Comment: As a temporary solution I decided to perform the check in defaultLayout and treat `CreateProfileR` as a special case, but that still seems hackish to me.